# slider code is working but its JS is not working in Angular

Tags: javascript, jquery, angularjs

Slider code is working OK.

But below mention code is the JS of slider which is not working because of which images are not being able to change automatically or manually

```
(function( $ ) {

    //Function to animate slider captions 
    function doAnimations( elems ) {
        //Cache the animationend event in a variable
        var animEndEv = 'webkitAnimationEnd animationend';

        elems.each(function () {
            var $this = $(this),
                $animationType = $this.data('animation');
            $this.addClass($animationType).one(animEndEv, function () {
                $this.removeClass($animationType);
            });
        });
    }

    //Variables on page load 
    var $myCarousel = $('#carousel-example-generic'),
        $firstAnimatingElems = $myCarousel.find('.item:first').find("[data-animation ^= 'animated']");

    //Initialize carousel 
    $myCarousel.carousel();

    //Animate captions in first slide on page load 
    doAnimations($firstAnimatingElems);

    //Pause carousel  
    $myCarousel.carousel('pause');


    //Other slides to be animated on carousel slide event 
    $myCarousel.on('slide.bs.carousel', function (e) {
        var $animatingElems = $(e.relatedTarget).find("[data-animation ^= 'animated']");
        doAnimations($animatingElems);
    });  
    $('#carousel-example-generic').carousel({
        interval:3000,
        pause: "false"
    });

})(jQuery);
```

Comment: what are you asking?

Comment: @Riscie i am using a slider in angular... Sliders HTML is working fine... But its images are not changig autoatically ad not even on clicking the next or prevus buttons... May b there is some problem in its jquery code (mentioned above)... So i need some help regaring this code